# How to profile distributed TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, multi-gpu

I have a simple distributed setup in TF (each step roughly corresponds to a `tf.Session.run` call)

1. Parent makes changes to variables on the device `'/job:parent'` via a session with a target for the sole parent task.
2. Several child processes `tf.assign` the parent variables to local variables sitting on `'/job:child/task:<child index>'`.
3. Each child process then does a bunch of calculations with its own local variables on its own TF device.

The children all have their own master sessions, connected to their personal child task targets.

My setup is either a single GPU or multiple (2) GPUs that are sharded among the parent and children. There are much more children than total GPUs (the memory and compute density are small enough that a GPU cannot be fully utilized by a single child task).

Even with many children, I still find that GPU utilization is low in both single and multiple GPU cases. I suspect that it is the `assign` operation. These are local GPUs, so it should be possible to execute the `assign` op via DMA, a vanilla GPU copy (if on the same GPU), or nccl, but I worry that by default TF will be transferring data over local gRPC sockets.

I have several questions:

1. Is my data transfer understanding correct?
2. The TF [profiler](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/profiler) seems directed seems directed to single-process workflows, measuring when ops get executed, etc., within a single session. How can I combine logs from multiple remote sessions? Will `tf.RunMetadata` capture the gRPC latency?
3. If I was to run all `tf.assign` ops on the parent session, doing every copy on each child index, would this avoid the gRPC call?